# Multiple Spring Integration flows as workers to consume from many SQS queues

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-function

I have many `SQS` queues to which I have to attach `workers` to consume and process messages (using `spring integration flow`). My initial thought is to have a single `spring boot` application with 1 channel per SQS queue(`spring integration aws`).

This will be like `1 SQS -> 1 Channel -> 1 Flow`

However, this might get into `maintainability`, `deployment`, `memory` issues and we won't be able to scale each worker independently. It sounds like a `monolith of workers`. Another option is to create a `spring cloud function` per `worker` type and deploy them as `lambda`.

Is there any other solution for this scenario in the `spring stack` (I want to use `spring integration` and `reactor`), such that we can scale every worker independently and also manage deployment of every worker independently (*may sound like a `microservice` for each worker, but it does not have a domain, just some processing logic like validations, invoke some api, store to database*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it doesn't have any domain and REST endpoints, you still can treat it as a microservice since it is activated when the message is consumed from the SQS queue. Therefore your direction with Spring Boot + Spring Integration AWS is correct. You just expose an SQS queue as a configuration property and deploy your application into a desired environment with appropriate scaling policy.

Yes, you probably still can write a Spring Cloud Function for AWS Lambda, but no one stops you to do a Spring Integration logic in the function body.

Comment: Thanks! I have a lot of queues, so if I do `1 spring boot per SQS`, then that's a lot small projects (even if I use maven multi-module) and if I use 1 spring boot for all queues, then the only option to scale is through `task-executors` at channel level to scale workers independent of each other. I am looking at using `kubernetes` auto-scale for each worker. Any suggestions or may be I am missing something?

Comment: I think it still going to scale properly since you are going to have several instances of the same application, so it may even look for you as that task executor.